# Equivalent of Qt.createQmlObject in C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Within QML, I can dynamically create a component (rather than loading it from a file) by calling `Qt.createQmlObject`. Example:

```
Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 1.0; Rectangle {color: "red"; width: 20; height: 20}', parent, "dynamicPath");
```

Is there way to do the same from C++ code? It doesn't necessarily have to involve parsing QML—I'm just looking for a way to, for example, dynamically create and attach a `Rectangle` or `TextField` to a QML document from C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the deprecated Qt Quick 1? Given that you have:

```
QDeclarativeView *view = ...;
QDeclarativeItem *parent = ...;
```

You can do:

```
QDeclarativeEngine *engine = view->engine();
QDeclarativeComponent component(engine);
component.setData("import QtQuick 1.0; Rectangle {color: \"red\"; width: 20; height: 20}", QUrl("dynamicPath"));
QDeclarativeItem *item = qobject_cast<QDeclarativeItem *>(component.create());
Q_ASSERT(item);
item->setParentItem(parent);
```

If you are actually using Qt Quick 2 instead, [you'd replace](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-porting-qt5.html) `QDeclarative*` with `QQml*` and `QQuick*`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! And no, I'm not on Qt Quick 1—I copied the sample snippet from some apparently out-of-date docs.

Comment: Is the `QUrl("dynamicPath")` documented somewhere ? Or is it just some name you gave ?

Comment: From the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcomponent.html#setData): "If _url_ is provided, it is used to set the component name and to provide a base path for items resolved by this component." - typically people pass an empty URL. If you get an error, passing it something non-empty just makes it clear where the error comes from.